# multiple conditions to a if loop python

Tags: python

Hello I'm having some problems with some code I am writing for a school and its not working. It wont run through the whole loop but all the code looks right to me. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
   User_Input = input ( "Please enter a message that is no longer than 7 characters." )
    User_Input_Length = len ( User_Input )  
    if     {  User_Input_Length >= 7 
         and  User_Input_Length == 1
    }:
    print ( "Your message is odd." )
    elif   {  User_Input_Length >= 7
         and  User_Input_Length == 3
    }:
    print ( "Your message is odd." )
    elif   {  User_Input_Legnth >= 7
         and  User_Input_Length == 5
    }:
    print ( "Your message is odd." )
    elif   {  User_Input_Length >= 7
         and  User_Input_Length == 7
    }:
    print ( "Your message is odd" )
    elif   {  User_Input_Length >= 7
         and  User_Input_Length == 2
    }:
    print ( "Your message is even" )
    elif   {  User_Input_Length >= 7
         and  User_Input_Length == 4
    }:
    print ( "Your message is even" )
    elif   {  User_Input_Length >= 7   
         and  User_Input_Length == 6
    }:
    print ( "Your string is even" )
    else:
    print ( "The string is too long." )
    print ( "Goodbye" )
```

Comment: You can use the `modulo method` (aka `%` operator) to divide by `2` and check if the `rest == 1`. If so, you have an odd number, otherwise, if `rest == 0`, it'll be an even number.

Comment: `User_Input_Length >= 7 and  User_Input_Length == 1` ... Um, think about that for a second. How does that "look right"?

Answer (score 3):

You're not testing what you think you are. Your expressions look like:

```
{ User_Input_Length >= 7 and User_Input_Length == 1 }
```

In Python, `{}` encloses a `set` or `dict` (or comprehension of either). This is thus a set containing one `bool` value. Per [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), any set that contains members is regarded as True, so your first test will be the only branch taken.

Secondly, the inner (unchecked) condition tests `User_Input_Length` for simultaneously being 7 or greater **and** some other value; only the one with 7 could ever be true.

Answer (score 1):

Those braces are for defining sets, and a non-empty set always evaluates to true, so your code will always evaluate the first if.

Python doesn't requires parenthesis (or braces) around if statements.

Answer (score 0):

you must use parentheses for the parameters of the `if` condition, and be careful about the placement of your code blocks: unlike C which uses `;` as a delimiter, python knows your block is over only because it jumps to the next line.

```
if(1 < 2) and (2 < 3):
    print("true")
elif(1 > 2):
    print("false")
```